# PHP: Nested for loops with if statement inside not executing

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops, execution-time

I have the following PHP code that gives a "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" message whenever it runs. If I remove the "if()" statement inside the second for loop the code runs without any problems. I cannot figure out why the "if()" statement would cause this error.

```
    for ($i=1;$i<=$nParam;$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<=$nParam-1;$j++){
           if ($j=$i-1){
                //do something
           }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a value, not comparing.

Use:

```
if ($j === $i-1){
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. You are using the assignment `=` operator instead of the comparison `==` operator:

```
if ($j=$i-1){ // <-- HERE
```

change it to

```
if ($j==$i-1){
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` for your if statement. The way you have it at the moment is continuously resetting the value of `$j` to 0, which is making it loop for ever.

Answer (score 1):

Change `($j=$i-1)` it to

```
  if ($j == $i-1){
        //do something
   }
```

- == is for comparison
- = is for assignment

hope this help.